# How do I sort an array in PHP by a value that's inside of a json formatted string?

Tags: php, arrays

I want the array below to be sorted by the `sortOrder`value that's inside the json string. I'm not sure how to do this with the usort/ksort/asort type functions that PHP provides.

Do I have to build my own logic for this or is there some method I am unaware of? I **do not** have access to changing this format, so don't mind pointing out it's stupid :)

```
Array (
    [0] => Array(
        [name] => Apple
        [json] => {
            "type" : "Fruit",
            "sortOrder" : 2
        }
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [name] => Potato
        [json] => {
            "type" : "Fruit",
            "sortOrder" : 1
        }
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
usort($array, function (array $a, array $b) {
    $a = json_decode($a['json'], true);
    $b = json_decode($b['json'], true);
    return $a['sortOrder'] - $b['sortOrder'];
});
```

However, this requires you to repeatedly decode JSON, which slows things down somewhat. It'd be better to decode all the JSON in advance:

```
$array = array_map(function (array $values) {
    $json = json_decode($values['json'], true);
    return $values + array('sortOrder' => $json['sortOrder']);
}, $array);

usort($array, function (array $a, array $b) {
    return $a['sortOrder'] - $b['sortOrder'];
});

$array = array_map(function (array $values) {
    unset($values['sortOrder']);
    return $values;
}, $array);
```

Comment: Without knowing the internals of `usort`, wouldn't this call `json_decode` *a lot* on every single item and not just once (in order to compare with all the other values)?

Comment: Yes, it would. See my addition.