# Custom sorting in php

Tags: php, json, sorting

I've built a site, which automatically scans a folder for .json files, that are containing "title","subtitle" and "article". Then my php goes trough all these and echoes them in nice div tags and everything.

To mantain the desired order of the articles so far I've been relying on the filenames of each json files, giving them a name like: "01.The first article", "02.The second"  and so on.

I was wondering I could sort all the files based on something I store inside of them. Like having an extra field in the json file just for the order, and then the php reads out the order value from each file.

So far my code is this:

```
if (file_exists($location)) {
    $articleList = array_diff(scandir($location), array('..', '.','contact.php')); //the jsons are stored in $location

    foreach ($articleList as $item => $itemValue) { //remove any found directories(subfolders) since those can't be read.
        if (is_dir($location . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $itemValue)) {
            unset($articleList[$item]);
        }
    }

    //probably here I would sort the $articleList based on the value of what's inside the files found.
    foreach ($articleList as $key => $value) {
        displayArticles($value,$folder); //this calls another function that echoes the contents.
    }
} else {
    include_once(rootFolder.'/php/errorPage.php');
    displayError("404");
}

function displayArticles($articleTitle, $folder) { //this is the function that echoes all out.
    global $location;

    if (file_exists($location . '/' . $articleTitle)) {
        $getArticle = file_get_contents($location . '/' . $articleTitle);
        $article = json_decode($getArticle, true);

        echo "\n\t<div class='article'>";
        if (!empty($article['title'])) {
            echo "\n\t\t<div class='title'><h1>";
            echo '<a href="./index.php?content='.$folder;
            echo '&amp;article=';
            echo urlencode($articleTitle).'">';
            echo $article['title'].'</a>';
            echo '</h1></div>';
         } //...and so on
```

How I imagine would do this, that after(or during?) the function does the scandir, reads out the order from the jsons, and then sorts the $articlelist.

Do I want too much? :)

Comment: Look at this answer: [Sort array by a value inside a json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809247/how-do-i-sort-an-array-in-php-by-a-value-thats-inside-of-a-json-formatted-strin)

Comment: Thanks for showing me this answer. However I'm not experienced enough to apply this to my code. :D I don't give up though... :)